# Undoing stack view from storyboard

Tags: ios, uikit, xcode7, uistackview

Xcode 7's interface builder allows stackview to be easily created around subviews via the click of the "Stack" button.  However, there seems no way to "unstack" the subviews from a stackview.  Is there a way to do this in interface builder?

Comment: As far as I know, this is comparable with putting view onto a another view. In this case, this has to be by hand as well.

Answer (score 21):

Select the stackview you want to break then click Editor -> Unembed

Comment: but in the top level stack view(the one with no children),the Unembed option just disable..I struggling how to remove it..can u give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Subviews in the stack are children of the stack. In the "Document outline" just select the subviews and drag them out of the stack view. Then you can delete the stackview.